# Django: Separate queryset into two sets

Tags: python, django

I have a Book class and a Wish class. Users can search for a book title and see a list of all users who have this book in their (available for trade) Book list. I want to separate this list into two lists of "perfect matches" and "possible matches". Perfect matches occur when another user has the book you are searching for in their Book list and your Book list contains at least one book from their Wish list. Possible matches are the rest of the users who have this book in their Book list. Here is the code I have so far:

```
results = Book.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query)).distinct()

books = Book.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            
for result in results:
   wishes = Wish.objects.filter(user=result.user)
   matches = books.filter(name__in=wishes.values_list('name'))
   if not matches:
      print("Not a perfect match.")
   else:
      print("This is a perfect match!")
```

I am able to check whether the result is a perfect match or not, but not sure how to "push" the result into a new list. I know you can't actually create a queryset and append objects like a list, but I can't think of a query that will return results that satisfy all the above conditions either. How can I separate "results" into two separate querysets/lists of perfect matches and possible matches?

Comment: Hi MSam! Do you really need two QuerySets? Perhaps just two lists would fit also? 
I am not sure ... how can you determine a users book list? `Book.objects.filter(user=someone)`?

Comment: @MSam could you update your question with your models (or, preferably, simplified versions of them that just include the fields defining the relations between them)?

Comment: @YvesHary yes, that is how you filter for all books for a particular user

Comment: @natka_m both book and wish models have just two fields: name and user